# Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3 - Possibly Related to Azure SDK

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, raspberry-pi, azure-api-apps, azure-sdk

Im having a heck of time with this. I was following along with this [doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/build-an-azure-app-service-to-record-raspberry-pi-sensor-data/) to connect a Raspberry Pi to an Azure SQL DB and it first instructed to download the [azure-sdk](/questions/tagged/azure-sdk).

After doing so, [visual-studio-2015](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2015) has been largely non functional. At first, no project templates were loading in the Project Creating menu. After searching around a while, I managed to fix that. Now, after creating a Web App for the Azure Api Service, I'm trying to add a REST API Client to the UWP project. This fails with the following exception:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Method 'RestartGateway' in type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.APIApps.Impl.VsAzureAPIService' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.Impl, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' does not have an implementation.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.AzureWebSitesService.GetAzureAPIService()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.RESTAPIClient.VisualStudio.MicroserviceReferenceCommandHandler.AddApiAppClientForActiveProject()
```

I'm really at a loss here. I have tried to repair Visual Studio, and a full uninstall and reinstall still to no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!